# rails 4 множественный выбор с автокомплитом во вложенной форме

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Задача**
Позволить юзеру выбрать языки, которыми он владеет.

**Модели**
User

```
has_many :fluent_languages, foreign_key: 'user_id'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :fluent_languages,
                              allow_destroy: true,
                              reject_if: proc { |attributes|     attributes['user_id'].blank? || attributes['language_id'].blank? }
```

FluentLanguage

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :language
```

Language

```
has_many :fluent_languages, foreign_key: 'language_id'
```

Хочется, чтобы селект выглядел вот [так](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple)

Моя попытка:

```
<%= f.fields_for :fluent_languages do |fluent_language| %>
<%= fluent_language.text_field :user_id, :type => 'hidden' %>
<%= fluent_language.autocomplete_field :language_id, autocomplete_language_language_users_path, 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true, :placeholder => 'Укажите языки через запятую' %>
<% end %>
```

Записывает в парамсы это

```
"7"=>{"user_id"=>"15", "language_id"=>["Английский,"]}}
```

а хочется, чтобы запись была как у обычного селекта:

```
"4"=>{"user_id"=>"15", "language_id"=>["1995"], "id"=>"1"}
```

Еще одна проблема - мультиселект с автокомплитом выводится для каждой записи из fluent_languages.
Еще одна проблема - выбранные по дефолту значения это ид языков, а не названия.

Как решить эти проблемы? Или как решить задачу по-другому?

Comment: Сразу вопрос: зачем вам промежуточная таблица? Если, только задания уровня ради, но судя по условию задачи вы уровень знания языка не собираетесь задавать.... если так я б советовал просто убрать промежуточную таблицу. дальше, у вас выборка языков должна попадать не в `language_id`, а в `language_ids`, тогда при обновлении записи пользователя, он получит в языки те, которые выбрал. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` нужен скорее для того, чтобы можно было создавать и удалять зависимые записи, а не просто выбирать. Естественно не забывайте пропускать их через сильные параметры =))